# On Android Studio 2.2.3 Gradle sync failed: Cause: error=13, Permission denied on Linux Mint 18

Tags: android-studio, permission-denied, android-studio-2.2

On Android Studio 2.2.3 when I am creating a new project or opening previous projects then the following pop ups:

> Gradle sync started 7:55:26 AM Gradle sync failed: Cause: error=13,
>   Permission denied
>              Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

what should I do? Please help. This is important.

Comment: Maybe you don't have write Access to SDK directory?

Comment: I give access to SDK directory but it is not working anyway. Same error.

Answer (score 31):

On Android Studio folder, do

```
chmod 777 * -R
```

I think this not the best answer but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks but I have already reinstalled it and now it is working correctly.

Comment: Gradle starts building now. Mind elaborate the '755' and '-R' part, what does it means?

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by going to the directory that contained the android-studio folder, which in my case was `/usr/local`
i.e `cd /usr/local`
then I ran:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R android-studio
```

It even fixed my font not displaying properly.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Gradle starts building now. Mind elaborate the '755' and '-R' part, what does it means?

Comment: @InfiniteLoops 755 means the owner which is root will read, write and execute in the directory. The group and others will only read and execute in the directory.

Comment: @InfiniteLoops -R means Recursive, by using this you can change files and directories recursively.

Answer (score 0):

go the log files & see the issue. Most of the times it will access denied to jdk. **Try changing the java path** from android inbuilt jdk to any other version and refresh the project