# App Actions Test Tool v3.0.0: No Android Module with actions file reference found

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions, android-slices

I'm implementing google app actions with slices and I want to test the voice assistant commands using:
 **App Actions Test Tool v3.0.0 and Android Studio 3.5.1**

The app has four different flavors, also for the specific flavour the released apk is uploaded to the playstore so when I try to launch the App Actions Test, it is displaying the message:

> App Actions Test Tool v3.0.0: No Android Module with actions file
>   reference found. 
>   You need one Android Module with an actions file
>   reference.

Althought I have the actions file already imlemented the plugin is still displaying the same error, what could be the cause whereas the file **actions.xml** is inside the XML folder.

Comment: This means the plugin cannot resolve the `<meta-data>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and then locate your xml file. You should double check where your manifest entry points to and that it can be resolved for the right flavor.

Comment: Another possibility is that if you're using an Android build variant different than `release`. Make sure you always use `release`. Build variants will be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause of the problem was a permission error.

On Android Studio folder, do

```
chmod 777 * -R
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039876/601147